# If $f\colon X\to Y$ is injective there is a $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=Id_X$

Tags: functions

How to prove that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is injective there is a $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_X$. I know that it is an if and only if, but I have already proved the reciprocal.

Answer (score 2):

> *Assuming $X\neq \emptyset$*

Let $c\in X$.

The $g$ you want (set-theoretically speaking) is $$g:=\{(y,x)\in Y\times X\, :\, (x,y)\in f\}\cup \left(\left(Y\setminus f(X) \right)\times\{c\}\right)$$

**Addition**: Morally, you define $$g(y):=\begin{cases}c\text{ if } y\notin f(X)\\\text{the only }x\in X\text{ such that }f(x)=y\text{ if }y\in f(X)\end{cases}$$

Comment: Both this answer and the question tacitly assume that $X\neq\varnothing$.  If $X$ is empty and $Y$ isn't, then the result is false.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add it. I did not remember whether the definition was $\emptyset^Y=\emptyset$ or $\emptyset^Y=\{\emptyset\}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f$ injective for each $y \in f(X)$ there exists only one $x \in A$ such that $y = f(x)$. Write $x = g(y)$. This will defined a function $$g:f(A) \to X$$ such that $g(f(x)) = x$, for all $x \in X$.

To complete the definition of $g$ we fix $x_0 \in X$ such that $g(y) = x_0$ for any $y \in Y - f(X)$.